# Is there a way to prevent the log of requests and responses in the scenarios in the karate-report?

Tags: json, bdd, karate

When scripts that I write with APIs with very large responses get an error, karate-report cannot be loaded, so I want to block the response line.
(In When method post / When method get step)

Comment: if this doesn't help, please contribute code: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#report-verbosity